# array.map is not a function even though I have it typed correctly

Tags: javascript

I am wondering why I'm getting this error message? But array.map is correct in how I'm stating it?

> /home/ccuser/workspace/credit-card-checker/main.js:40
> newArr = array.map((element, index) => index % 2 === 1 ? element * 2 : element);
> ^

> TypeError: array.map is not a function
> at validateCred

```js
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];

const validateCred = (array) => {
  let newArr = [];
  let newestArr = [];
  let reducedResult = 0;
  const reducer = (previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue;
  if (array.length % 2 === 0) {

    newArr = array.map((element, index) => index % 2 === 0 ? element * 2 : element);
  } else {
    newArr = array.map((element, index) => index % 2 === 1 ? element * 2 : element);
  }
  newestArr = newArr.map((element) => element > 9 ? element - 9 : element);

  let sum = newestArr.reduce((prev, curr) => prev += curr);
  return sum % 10 === 0
};

const findInvalidCards = (nestedArray) => {
  let invalidArray = [];
  invalidArray = nestedArray.forEach((element) => validateCred(element) === false);
  return invalidArray;
};

findInvalidCards(valid1);
```

Comment: My guess is that `array` isn't an array.  What parameter are you passing to validateCred?

Comment: Sorry I will edit my post to show the other code. One moment

Comment: Your array isn't nested, so you end up trying to call `.map` on numbers.

Comment: `nestedArray` is an array of integers, so when you call `validateCred(element)`, `element` is a number and not an array.

Comment: Ahhhh okay that makes sense! thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

valid1 is supposed to be an array of arrays, so here I just wrap another set of square brackets.

Also, forEach always returns undefined, so I changed it to use map instead.

```js
const valid1 = [[4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8]];

const validateCred = (array) => {
  let newArr = [];
  let newestArr = [];
  let reducedResult = 0;
  const reducer = (previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue;
  if (array.length % 2 === 0) {

    newArr = array.map((element, index) => index % 2 === 0 ? element * 2 : element);
  } else {
    newArr = array.map((element, index) => index % 2 === 1 ? element * 2 : element);
  }
  newestArr = newArr.map((element) => element > 9 ? element - 9 : element);

  let sum = newestArr.reduce((prev, curr) => prev += curr);
  return sum % 10 === 0
};

const findInvalidCards = (nestedArray) => {
  let invalidArray = [];
  invalidArray = nestedArray.map((element) => ({cardNumber: element.join(""), isValid: validateCred(element)}));
  return invalidArray;
};

console.log(findInvalidCards(valid1));
```

Comment: wow that's really helpful! thanks very much. I didn't think of using .map! I tested the code there and that works perfectly but I've learned from that now